# Automatically Create a Work Item on new Pull Request

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, tfs-workitem

We would like to have task created when on new Pull Request .

What I would like to do is:

1. Find User Story Pull Request Review in Current Sprint
2. If not exist, create it.
3. Create Task Review Pull Request X under previous story.

That feature doesn't seem to exists in Azure DevOps. Even simply creating a task on new pull request...

The Only way I can think of is through a Service Hook with a custom Web hook.

Can you guide me through this?

---

**Edit**
We are currently reviewing a solution using [Zapier](https://zapier.com/apps/azure-devops/integrations) but we cannot perform exactly what is described above, and it's a paid subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use custom app and run it through the task scheduler. Rest Api methods:

1. [View active pull requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). In my case, I use a service comment (like "Review task is created") in pull request. If I did not find it, I`ll create a task, link it to PR and add the service comment.
2. [Create task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples) and [link it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to pull request.

Here is the sample project: [Create and View Pull Requests](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2019/07/10/azure-devops-rest-api-21-create-and-view-pull-requests/)

Comment: Good idea I haven't thought about that... it's a lot simpler than building a custom Service Hook.

Comment: @moi_meme if above answer works, you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can force users to link pull request to an existing work item with [Branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#check-for-linked-work-items). this would not create a work item for them, but it would block them from creating a PR unless they link it to an existing work item. I think this is the only thing you can do out of the box.